# Restructuring the xml when reading

Tags: c#

I am want to convert the first datatable sturcture into second table structure as shown 
Please help me with the approach

```
F1      F2     F3     F4     F5
Group   1      2      3      4 
Design  5      6      7      8

F1      Value
Group   1   
Group   2   
Group   3   
Group   4
Design  5      
Design  6  
Design  7  
Design  8
```

Xml

```
<WK11>
  <F1>Group</F1> 
  </WK11>
<WK11>
  <F1>1</F1> 
  <F2>2</F2> 
  <F3>3</F3> 
  <F4>4</F4> 
</WK11>
<F1>Design</F1> 
  </WK11>
<WK11>
  <F1>5</F1> 
  <F2>6</F2> 
  <F3>7</F3> 
  <F4>8</F4> 
</WK11>
</WK11>
```

Comment: Is this XML?  If so, try posting the input XML and the output XML.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537399/rotating-sql-table

Comment: @Krik - i have posted the xml doc basically when you read this xml using dataset my datatable will have the format as shown in the first structure so now i need to convert this to second structure may be while reading xml itself

Comment: The XML you posted is invalid. Would you like to edit it and post the correct XML so that we know what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest getting the SQL Server to do it using the UNPIVOT clause, you can then read it as you desire. For more information, please refer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537399/rotating-sql-table)

Answer (score -1):

Use Linq for DataSet or Linq for Xml.

Comment: hi mendy...
can it be done in dotnet 2.0 framework if yes pls help me with the sample code