# Rotating sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

my sql talble has the following structure

```
F1      F2     F3     F4     F5 
Group   1      2      3      4  
Design  5      6      7      8
```

now i want to read this and return a query result as show below please help

```
F1      Value 
Group   1    
Group   2    
Group   3    
Group   4 
Design  5       
Design  6   
Design  7   
Design  8
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Comment: SQL 2005 - but basically i am looking for a query for this and should not be in the backend

Comment: but the query WILL run on the backend (=DB)?

Comment: yes basically i should be able to call the query from my code (Csharp)

Comment: You can execute any arbitrary SQL query from your client code though, and it may even be the best option.

Answer (score 5):

SQL 2005 Introduced a [pivot and matching unpivot clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), and this looks like a prime case, if you're unable to fix the underlying schema

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `UNION` operator:

```
SELECT F1, F2 AS VALUE FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT F1, F3 AS VALUE FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT F1, F4 AS VALUE FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT F1, F5 AS VALUE FROM TABLE
```

Comment: but my rows are not fixed.. it can have 150 rows and 120 columns

Comment: @Satish This approach would not change dependant of the row count - just the column count, which will remain static per table.

Comment: yes but for 120 cols will the query be not too large and will give performance hits

Comment: @Sathish in that case look at the UNPIVOT clause that I previously mentioned.

Comment: @Sathish: besides UNPIVOT you might consider refactoring that DB.